# OpenGL outdated version (can't find glMultiDrawElements on header)

Tags: opengl, version

I was trying to use the function glMultiDrawElements while studying OpenGL (using red book) but couldn't.

I checked the header "gl.h" and the function wasn't there so I checked the version on top of the header and it's 1.1. I know I need at least 1.4 to use it, but I have no idea on how to update it. I tried Windows Update but nothing.

This is probably a stupid question but all of this is new to me so I'm a bit confused... I'm using Visual C++ 2008 Express in case you need to know that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grab something like [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) in order to work with more recent versions of OpenGL. The headers that ship with Visual Studio are woefully outdated (probably for obvious reasons).